# Multiclass Decision Forest vs Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, decision-tree, prediction

How does Multiclass Decision Forest differ from Random Forest? What factors do they have in common? It appears there is not a clear answer on the web regarding this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Random forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) or random decision forests is an extension of the decision forests (ensemble of decision trees) combining [bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) and [random selection of features](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/598994/?arnumber=598994&tag=1) to construct a collection of decision trees with controlled variance.

A very good [paper from Microsoft research](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/decision-forests-for-classification-regression-density-estimation-manifold-learning-and-semi-supervised-learning/) you may consider to look at.