# concise distinction between “Decision Forest" and “Random Forest"

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

Looking for the best (clearest, shortest, brightest) 
concise distinction between the ML terms “Decision Forest" and “Random Forest"?

Note the similar and also unanswered question:
[Multiclass Decision Forest vs Random Forest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380783/multiclass-decision-forest-vs-random-forest)

Comment: see also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14595/are-decision-forests-and-random-forests-the-same-thing

Comment: It's not just similar, but *duplicate* to that question. Please do not duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

[Random forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) or random decision forests is an extension of the decision forests (ensemble of decision trees) combining [bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) and [random selection of features](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/598994/?arnumber=598994&tag=1) to construct a collection of decision trees with controlled variance.

Answer (score 0):

Random forest is an extension of random decision forest that includes [bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating). For details check the [original paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1010933404324) by Breiman or more lightweight description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest). Majority of well-known machine learning libraries, like Python's [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#random-forests), implements Random Forest.